# I am Using Recycler View but when i click on See all than app got back to previous activity instead of showing AllCategoryActivity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am facing issue from one week and i need help.

I am creating a food delivery app in which on menu page i mentioned categories and add a textview (SeeAll) to see more categories. I am using Recycler view but when i click on SeeAll text than app instead of showing me all categories page got back to the signin page.

[When click on SeeAll it goes back to signin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztp42.gif)

AllCategoryActivity.class

```
package com.example.quickgrocer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.quickgrocer.adapter.AllCategoryAdapter;
import com.example.quickgrocer.model.AllCategoryModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AllCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView AllCategoryRecycler;
    AllCategoryAdapter allCategoryAdapter;
    List<AllCategoryModel> allCategoryModelList;

    ImageButton back;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_category);

        back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);


        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AllCategoryActivity.this, Menu.class));
            }
        });

        AllCategoryRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.all_category);

        // adding data to model
        allCategoryModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        allCategoryModelList.add(new AllCategoryModel(1, R.drawable.ic_home_fruits));
        allCategoryModelList.add(new AllCategoryModel(2, R.drawable.ic_veggies));
        allCategoryModelList.add(new AllCategoryModel(3, R.drawable.ic_meat));
        allCategoryModelList.add(new AllCategoryModel(4, R.drawable.ic_fish));
        allCategoryModelList.add(new AllCategoryModel(5, R.drawable.ic_spices));
        allCategoryModelList.add(new AllCategoryModel(6, R.drawable.ic_egg));
        allCategoryModelList.add(new AllCategoryModel(7, R.drawable.ic_drink));
        allCategoryModelList.add(new AllCategoryModel(8, R.drawable.ic_cookies));
        allCategoryModelList.add(new AllCategoryModel(9, R.drawable.ic_juce));

        setCategoryRecycler(allCategoryModelList);

    }

    private void setCategoryRecycler(List<AllCategoryModel> allCategoryModelList) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        AllCategoryRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        allCategoryAdapter = new AllCategoryAdapter(this,allCategoryModelList);
        AllCategoryRecycler.setAdapter(allCategoryAdapter);
    }


 


}
```

AllCategoryModel

```
package com.example.quickgrocer.model;

public class AllCategoryModel {



    Integer id;
    Integer imageurl;

    public AllCategoryModel(Integer id, Integer imageurl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }

    public Integer getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id;}

    public Integer getImageurl() {return imageurl;}

    public void setImageurl(Integer imageurl) {this.imageurl = imageurl;}

}
```

AllCategoryAdapter

```
package com.example.quickgrocer.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.quickgrocer.R;
import com.example.quickgrocer.model.AllCategoryModel;

import java.util.List;

public class  AllCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllCategoryAdapter.AllCategoryViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private final List<AllCategoryModel> categoryList;

    public AllCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<AllCategoryModel> categoryList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AllCategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.all_category_row_items, parent, false);
        return new AllCategoryAdapter.AllCategoryViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AllCategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(categoryList.get(position).getImageurl());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }

    public class AllCategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        ImageView itemImage;

        public AllCategoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_img);

        }
    }

}
```

activity_all_category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AllCategoryActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_24"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select a category"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/all_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

all_category_row_items.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cookies"
        android:contentDescription="Item Img" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I tried all possible ways but still facing issue.

Comment: Question doesn't provide enough information. Where's the `See all` Button click?